# Error creating GitHub release: Provider setting not found. Parameter name: auth_token

Tags: github-api, appveyor

So I decided to try to deploy my app using appveyor and github. I followed instructions from the page:

- http://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/github

I basically went to:

- https://github.com/settings/tokens

click on **Generate new token**, I called it `appveyor` (under `Token description`). I selected only `public_repo` from the `Select scopes` section. Then copy paste the string (sha1?). Then went to my appveyor page:

- https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/encrypt

Copy/paste my `github` sha1 string, got another sha1 string in return, copy/pasted this string onto my `appveyor` YAML script:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malaterre/GDCM/master/appveyor.yml

But when I run it, I get a weird error saying:

> Error creating GitHub release: Provider setting not found. Parameter
>   name: auth_token

See:

- https://ci.appveyor.com/project/malaterre/gdcm/build/2.7.0.116

What did I missed from the instructions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing `# your encrypted token from GitHub` comment from a line with secure token?